# how to concatenate (variable + object key names) to get the object values in dot notation

Tags: javascript, loops

Assuming I've a JSON object like this:

```
var myObj = {
    'question1': {
        'option1': 'foo',
        'option2': 'bar',
        'option3': 'baz'
    },
    'question2': {
        ...
    },
    'question3': {
        ...
    }
};
```

And since its children always has a number in its keys, I want to do a loop and **concatenate** the loop's index to the object keys, and get the values in the dot notation method...

So, I guess to get the values, I need to do some thing like this:

```
myObj.'question'+i
```

How can I do the concatenation right?

Comment: Why aren't you using an array for this? `myObj.questions[i]` would make more sense.

Comment: Use the array-looking notation, myObj['question' + i]

Comment: `myObj['question' + i]` is the ideal way.

Comment: @jonrsharpe , I'm using an object because I want to use key/value pairs. It's not necessarily to be indexed keys, I mean, I won't be `question1,question2,question3,...`, it may pass some numbers, you know

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Simply do

```
myObj['question'+i]
```

This is because the dot operator would not accept string with it as per javascript. So you will have to use square brackets instead which is often used to access properties of an object dynamically.